# Tell It Like It Is

Tags: riddle

> I can be used in many different circumstances,
> Often to set things above the rest.
> However when some people put me in context,
> My use is ambiguous at best!
>
> But although I'm often well,
> There's one thing I must tell.
> Sometimes you "don't want me", you may defend,
> But in music you might find me at the end!

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Fine.

Often to set things above the rest.

> Finer things in life

However when some people put me in context,
My use is ambiguous at best!

> "It's fine, I guess."

But although I'm often well,

> Feeling fine after an illness

There's one thing I must tell.
Sometimes you "don't want me", you may defend,

> Nobody wants to pay a court/ticket fine

But in music you might find me at the end!

> Often written at the end of music.  Italian for "end"

What am I?

Answer (score 3):

I think it could be

> a colon aka ":"

I can be used in many different circumstances,
Often to set things above the rest.

> Whenever we want to name several points or arguments. The first line, the header of the list, is always first/above the rest and ends with a colon.
>  *"This line is above the rest:
>
>  - item 1
>
>  - item 2"*

However when some people put me in context,
My use is ambiguous at best!

> *Ambigous* may hint towards the fact that a colon is made of two dots. Plus, it's used with quotes sometimes, which we all know can be ambigious.

But although I'm often well,
There's one thing I must tell.

> This could be to fill the lines :P Or another hint towards quotes. *There is one thing I must tell* could be replaced by a colon actually since it often indicates someone starts talking.

Sometimes you "don't want me", you may defend,

> Still figuring that one out

But in music you might find me at the end!

> If I remember correctly a colon is used at the end of a line or a certain part within the play to tell the musician to repeat. 
>  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark

> Bridge?

I can be used in many different circumstances,

> bridge, pool bridge, music bridge.

Often to set things above the rest.

> It's what bridges do.

However when some people put me in context,
My use is ambiguous at best!

> Bridging a gap.

But although I'm often well,
There's one thing I must tell.
Sometimes you "don't want me", you may defend,

> Defending a bridge is common strategy.

But in music you might find me at the end!

> A musical bridge is sometimes at the end of a song.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Honesty/Truth?

I can be used in many different circumstances,

> You can be honest in many situations

Often to set things above the rest.

> Honesty is valued in relationships and friendships

However when some people put me in context,
My use is ambiguous at best!

> Even though a person may tell the truth, they may not tell the whole truth

But although I'm often well,

> Truth is usually favoured

There's one thing I must tell.
Sometimes you "don't want me", you may defend,

> Honest answers are sometimes unwelcome, e.g "Does this dress make me look fat?"

But in music you might find me at the end!

> Not too sure about this one... Billy Joel has a song called Honesty?

Answer (score 0):

Are you a:

> Bar?

I can be used in many different circumstances,
Often to set things above the rest.

> Shelf made out of Bars. "Higher bar".

However when some people put me in context,
My use is ambiguous at best!

> Bar can mean different things. Candy-bar, Bar(pub), Could be a dairy bar. A counter that can sell anything.

But although I'm often well,
There's one thing I must tell.
Sometimes you "don't want me", you may defend,

> Bar(red) from something at the Bar(courtroom)? Defend yourself using law at a courtroom.

But in music you might find me at the end!

> A bar denotes end of beat, double bar end of music.